# Delete or move horizontal separator lines in CPropertySheet Wizard MFC dialog

Tags: mfc, propertysheet

I have a CPropertySheet set in Wizard Mode which I want to resize. Microsoft provides a tricky way to do this in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143291/en-us).

How would you delete or remove the two horizontal separator lines after the header and before the buttons ?

[image: sample dialog]

Comment: AFAIK you can not delete them. They are part of the parent dialog template, or they may be part of the style of the child dialog. Use Spy++ to determine this. But with a common control manifest this dialog looks completely different.

Comment: What do you mean by common control manifest?

Comment: The manifest to get the XP-Style. Common Control Ver. 6 manifest.